# iphone scanning a dat file for data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, streamreader

I am trying to remake a program I have made in C# in OBJ-C.In C# I used streamreader to search the data file for the line I am looking for then convert that line into a string that I can work with.

I have looked at NSScanner but I'm not sure if thats quite waht I'm looking for but I'm by no means a cocoa expert.

All I would like to be able to do is have it search a data file for an occurance of a string, then when/if it finds an occurance of that string, it returns the line that string was found on as a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the data input a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data file isn't to large to fit in memory, you can just load it into a string and search it using string methods.  For example:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file.dat"];
NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
for (NSString *line in [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"])
    if (!NSEqualRanges([line rangeOfString:searchString], NSMakeRange(NSNotFound,0)))
        return line;
```

Comment: whats too big? the dat file is 462 kb

Comment: 462 kb is no problem.  I wouldn't even worry about anything under 10 MB.

Comment: `NSRangeMake` should be `NSMakeRange`.